# Angular Custom Component databinding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following use case where i want to pass a part of a complex object to an angular component.

```
<app-component [set]="data.set"></app-component>
```

Now i want the object 'data.set' in the parent class to always be the same like the object 'set' inside the child class.

If I instead do it the following way, both objects are the same and changes are "synced".

```
<app-component [set]="set"></app-component>
```

How can i achieve this behaviour, when binding *'data.set'* instead of *'set'*, without manually triggering an *EventEmitter*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need changes done to `set` within `app-component` to be visible in parent component, then, you need to use two-way binding.

```
<app-component [(set)]="data.set"></app-component>
```

In the `app-component.component.ts` file, you need to declare two members:

```
   @Input()
   public set: any;

   @Ouput()
   public setChange:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

And whenever, there is change to the value of `set`, you need to emit the updated value.

```
   this.setChange.emit(newVal);
```

You could refer to [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html) if you need more details.